# Image of Fourier transform for finite non-abelian groups

Tags: rt.representation-theory, finite-groups, fourier-transform

I am working on the Fourier transform over finite non-abelian groups, specifically following [Diaconis](https://jdc.math.uwo.ca/M9140a-2012-summer/Diaconis.pdf). He defines it as follows (p.7):

Let $P$ be a probability on a finite group $G$. The Fourier transform of $P$ at the representation $\rho$ is the matrix
\begin{equation*}
\widehat{P}(\rho) = \sum_{s\in G}P(s)\rho(s)
\end{equation*}

My understanding is that the Fourier transform is a ring isomorphism between the set of functions $L(G) = \{f: G \rightarrow \mathbb{C}\}$ (with the operations of pointwise addition and convolution) and some other set (with pointwise addition and pointwise multiplication) via the convolution theorem.  What is this other set?

Comment: the ring isomorphism is explained in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform_on_finite_groups#Relationship_with_representation_theory

Comment: @CarloBeenakker I've seen that characterization but it's still unclear to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The transform, which is a ring isomorphism,
$$
P \mapsto \widehat{P} = \sum_{g\in G} P(g)g
$$
goes from your $L(G)$ to the group algebra ${\mathbb C}G$. The convolution corresponds to the multiplication in the group algebra:
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GroupAlgebra.html

If you apply an irreducible representation $\rho$ to the righthand side, this corresponds to the projection to the matrix direct summand in the Wedderburn decomposition:
$$
{\mathbb C}G = \oplus_{\mu\in Irr(G)} M_{d(\mu)} \rightarrow M_{d(\rho)}
$$
where $d(\rho)$ is the degree of your representation. Thus, you end up in the matrix algebra, while the convolution corresponds to the matrix multiplication. It is no longer an isomorphism, just a homomorphism.